# Is there any way where I can use hibernate 3 with wildfly 10?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

We have developed application and currently uses glassfish3122 sever , we want to migrate from glassfish to wildfly.
When I deploy project in wildfly 10, default hibernate they have provided is 5 and in our project we have used hibernate 3 so application throws exception.
I have tried excluding default hibernate using `"jboss-deployment-structure.xml"` but no luck.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Did you set `<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="hibernate3-bundled" />` in your `persistence.xml`?